# How to install bison 2.4.1 on ARM64 CPU (aarch64)?

Tags: arm, bison, arm64

I have downloaded bison2.4.1 on my Ubuntu 16.0.4 linux on ARM 64 Board. 
but, I cannot proceed any more, my problem is as below:

while I executed ./configure cmd, I got the error message as below:

```
checking for wctype.h... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking whether system is Windows or MSDOS... no
checking build system type... build-aux/config.guess: unable to guess system type

This script, last modified 2008-12-11, has failed to recognize
the operating system you are using. It is advised that you
download the most up to date version of the config scripts from

  http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.guess;hb=HEAD
and
  http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub;hb=HEAD

If the version you run (build-aux/config.guess) is already up to date, please
send the following data and any information you think might be
pertinent to <config-patches@gnu.org> in order to provide the needed
information to handle your system.

config.guess timestamp = 2008-12-11

uname -m = aarch64
uname -r = 4.4.77-rockchip-ayufan-136
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Thu Oct 12 09:14:48 UTC 2017

/usr/bin/uname -p = 
/bin/uname -X     = 

hostinfo               = 
/bin/universe          = 
/usr/bin/arch -k       = 
/bin/arch              = 
/usr/bin/oslevel       = 
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = 

UNAME_MACHINE = aarch64
UNAME_RELEASE = 4.4.77-rockchip-ayufan-136
UNAME_SYSTEM  = Linux
UNAME_VERSION = #1 SMP Thu Oct 12 09:14:48 UTC 2017
configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old bison version?

Answer (score 3):

Since the autotools packaged with bison 2.4.1 doesn't know anything about 64-bit ARM architectures, you need to tell configure not to bother trying to guess the machine:

```
./configure --build=unknown-unknown-linux
```

I don't believe that will cause problems, but I have no way to test it since I don't have an ARM64 board kicking about (and if I did, I wouldn't install a 10-year-old bison version on it.) But I did test that configure option on my machine; it configured and built fine, and then passed all the tests in the testsuite.

aarch64 support was added in bison 2.7, I think, but you'd be better off downloading a less ancient version of bison, which will almost certainly recognize your build environment by default and run with out problems on it.

Bison 3.0.5 was released last week; you can download it at https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bison/bison-3.0.5.tar.xz

Comment: checking whether system is Windows or MSDOS... no
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `aarch64-linux-gnu': machine `aarch64' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash build-aux/config.sub aarch64-linux-gnu failed

Comment: @jason: actually, that doesn't surprise me although it's a bit disappointing that there is no default linux build configuration. I should have been more explicit in my answer, and I've now edited it: get a new version of bison. If you think that won't work for some reason, pkease explain why not.

Comment: new version of bison works well in my arm board, but I tried to compile our corporation's solution which uses bison 2.4.1 for some specific reason so I need to install bison 2.4.1 on my board.. if possible I want to reconfigure the configure file...

Comment: It's hard to believe that there is an incompatibility between 2.4.1 and the current version that could not be fixed in a few minutes. However, I suppose your company isn't interested in doing that (although they should IMHO :). The problem here isn't bison, really; it's the manic way that autotools attempt to support hardware that only exists in the museum of retrocomputing. Anyway, I modified the suggested `--build` config argument to something which at least will complete the build process.

Comment: I gotta say that I think the whole thing is silly. These days, legacy machines are pretty rare and standardisation has proceeded to the point that you really don't need to deal with individual quirks of particular hardware. At least, not for software like bison, which is far from the raw metal.

Comment: Thanks for your kind information. today, I tested it again and it works.. "./configure --build=unknown-unknown-linux" works.... sorry for your confusion... Thanks again...

Comment: I can confirm this solution worked for compiling mysql 4.1 on Linux rockpi 5.8.13-rockchip64